# Powershell returns HTML code rather than Excel file when using invoke-webrequest

Tags: html, powershell

I'm trying to create a script to download an Excel file from a Sharepoint site.  This is the script:

`$FilePath = "https://example.com/SPREAD_SHEET.xlsx"`

`Invoke-WebRequest $FilePath -OutFile c:\temp`

The script downloads some HTML source code rather than downloading the Excel file.  I think this is due to our SSO solution.  If I manually browse to that URL in a web browser it opens up the Excel file rather than prompting me for username/password.

I'm trying to figure out how to create a header to provide my credentials to invoke-webrequest but I'm struggling.

Here's an excerpt of the HTML that is downloaded:

```
<form   name=""Login""  action=""/gmgameosso/UI/Login?AMAuthCookieGAMEp=AQIC5wM2LY4SfcwsKN671oA8AxdFBbOl8C3K7VVzjpS%2Bu3k%3D%40AAJTSQACMDIAAlMxAAIwNg%3D%3D%23""  method=""post"">"
<script> elmCount = 3; </script>"
<input name=""IDToken0"" type=""hidden"">"
<input name=""IDToken1"" type=""hidden"">"
<input name=""IDToken2"" type=""hidden"">"
<input name=""IDButton"" type=""hidden"">"

<input type=""hidden"" name=""goto"" value=""L1NTT1JlZGlyZWN0L21ldGFBbGlhcy9nbS9nYW1lL2lkcD9SZXFJRD1pZC0wMGY3N2ExMC04OWI4LTQzMTYtOGI0Yi05ZWZhYTZmMzdmZjA="">"
<input type=""hidden"" name=""gotoOnFail"" value="""">"
<input type=""hidden"" name=""SunQueryParamsString"" value=""QU1BdXRoQ29va2llR0FNRXA9QVFJQzV3TTJMWTRTZmN3c0tONjcxb0E4QXhkRkJiT2w4QzNLN1ZWempwUyt1M2s9QEFBSlRTUUFDTURJQUFsTXhBQUl3Tmc9PSMmcmVhbG09L2dtL2dhbWUmZm9yd2FyZD10cnVlJnNlcnZpY2U9bGRhcFNlcnZpY2Umbm9uZT0mc3BFbnRpdHlJRD1odHRwczovL2FkZnMuZ20uY29tL2FkZnMvc2VydmljZXMvdHJ1c3Q="">"
<input type=""hidden"" name=""encoded"" value=""true"">"
<input type=""hidden"" name=""dateStr"" value=""1420830736215"">"
<input type=""hidden"" name=""pageTimeOut"" value=""300"">"
<input type=""hidden"" name=""gx_charset"" value=""UTF-8""></form>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
$web = New-Object Net.WebClient

$web.DownloadFile("http://www.MyHost.com/Links.png", "C:\test.png");
```

Comment: That results in the following error:  Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."
At line:1 char:1
+ $test = $web.DownloadFile("https://example.com ...
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException

When using the invoke-webrequest cmdlet at least I get a 200 response (no authentication issues).

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a full file path for -OutFile or leave it blank to use current location.

You can try using -UseDefaultCredentials if you are using Integrated Windows Authentication for the website.

```
$FilePath = "https://example.com/SPREAD_SHEET.xlsx"
Invoke-WebRequest $FilePath -OutFile "c:\temp\Spread Sheet.xlsx" -UseDefaultCredentials
```

If you are not using Integrated Windows Authentication on the site, you can use the -SessionVariable parameter, parse the html you get back for the login page, fill in the login fields and use Invoke-Webrequest to send a POST with that login information to authenticate. You can then use that WebSession object to send further requests. See the [Example 2 for the Invoke-WebRequest](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx) help. There is a full example of signing into FaceBook in there.

Comment: I went down that rabbit hole and didn't have any luck.  I grab the forms property and modify the fields with the username and password.  But forms.action evaluates to /gmgameosso/UI/Login?AMAuthCookieGAMEp=AQIC5wM2LY4SfczHoQzcveSHidytRBLN85YUJyjvXUis8Jw%3D%40.  So when I try to submit the webrequest using invoke-webreqeust -uri (http://example.com/spreadsheet.xls + $form.action), it tries to hit an invalid URL.